# Is it possible to get wallet status (deposit and withdraw on or offline) and limits from CCXT?

Tags: python, ccxt

I am trying to use [CCXT](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) to create a table of currencies with their wallet status (whether deposit and withdraws are on or offline), plus the respective minimums (minimum to deposit, minimum to withdraw) and maximums (maximum to withdraw), i.e.

BTC | Deposit: ON  | Withdraw: ON | Minimum deposit: .01 | Minimum withdraw: .01 | Maximum withdraw: 10

I am looking to do this for Huobi's exchange, so if CCXT doesn't offer this ability, I may need to use Houbi's API [directly](https://huobiapi.github.io/doc).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fetchCurrencies` to get the **min and max withdraw amounts** (those amounts will depend on the chain). Fetch currencies returns a response like below

```
...
{
    "ZRX": {
        "active": true,
        "code": "ZRX",
        "fee": null,
        "id": "zrx",
        "info": { 
            # Unfiltered, non-unified response from the huobi api
            # Is not consistent across exchanges
        },
        "limits": {
            "amount": {
                "max": null,
                "min": null
            },
            "withdraw": {
                "max": null,
                "min": null
            }
        },
        "name": null,
        "networks": {
            "ERC20": {
                "active": true,
                "fee": 20.71036372,
                "id": "zrx",
                "info": {
                    "addrDepositTag": false,
                    "addrWithTag": false,
                    "baseChain": "ETH",
                    "baseChainProtocol": "ERC20",
                    "chain": "zrx",
                    "depositStatus": "allowed",
                    "displayName": "ERC20",
                    "fullName": "Ethereum",
                    "isDynamic": true,
                    "maxWithdrawAmt": "5000000.000000000000000000",
                    "minDepositAmt": "5",
                    "minWithdrawAmt": "10",
                    "numOfConfirmations": "12",
                    "numOfFastConfirmations": "12",
                    "transactFeeWithdraw": "20.71036372",
                    "withdrawFeeType": "fixed",
                    "withdrawPrecision": "8",
                    "withdrawQuotaPerDay": "5000000.000000000000000000",
                    "withdrawQuotaPerYear": null,
                    "withdrawQuotaTotal": null,
                    "withdrawStatus": "allowed"
                },
                "limits": {
                    "withdraw": {
                        "max": 5000000.0,
                        "min": 10.0
                    }
                },
                "network": "ERC20",
                "precision": 1e-08
            },
            ...
        },
        "precision": 1e-08
    }
}
```

You can then use `fetchDepositAddress`, `fetchWithdrawAddress`, `spotPrivateGetV2AccountWithdrawAddress`, `fetchDeposits`, and `fetchWithdrawals` to get the rest of the information you want. All together this would look like

```
import ccxt
import sys
import json
# import logging
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

print('python', sys.version)
print('CCXT Version:', ccxt.__version__)

exchange = ccxt.huobi({
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    "apiKey": '...',
    "secret": '...',
})
# exchange.verbose = True

currencies = exchange.fetchCurrencies()
for cur in currencies.keys():
    depositAddresses = exchange.fetchDepositAddress(cur)
    withdrawAddresses = exchange.fetchWithdrawAddresses('USDT') # Once the PR get's merged
    deposits = exchange.fetchDeposits(cur)
    withdraws = exchange.fetchWithdrawals(cur)
    # And then organize things how you want to get your table
```

---

**Note**

There's always a way to do anything that's done using the regular API with CCXT by using [implicit API methods](https://docs.ccxt.com/en/latest/manual.html#implicit-api). You can use these if there hasn't been a unified CCXT method written for the api endpoint you're trying to use (like with fetching the withdraw addresses), and it would look like

```
withdrawAddresses = huobi.spotPrivateGetV2AccountWithdrawAddress({"currency": "usdt"})
```

---

- Be careful not to overload the api with too many requests
- `fetchWithdrawAddress` is new, make sure you pull the latest CCXT

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just looping over the currencies in this manner:

```
    currencies = huobi.currencies  

    for item1 in currencies:  
        checkChains = currencies[item1]
        for item2 in checkChains['info']['chains']:
                print(item1,',',item2['chain'],',',item2['depositStatus'],',',item2['minDepositAmt'],',',item2['withdrawStatus'],',',item2['minWithdrawAmt'],',',item2['maxWithdrawAmt'],',',item2['transactFeeWithdraw'])
```

Though, your syntax looks much cleaner and offers helpful insight into how I could optimize here.